# Download file and display contents with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, download, html

I have a simple webpage which has a link, on pressing it a file is downloaded(rest web service call). I need to read the file and display the contents using javascript. How do I do this?

Comment: a text file which contains data in JSON format.

Comment: So is the file downloaded to the user's computer, but you also want a copy of the contents to appear in the webpage?

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the server where the REST web service is hosted, you can use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP).

Otherwise, you will have to work around the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restrictions.

As one possible workaround, you could set up a very simple [reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) (with [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html) if you are using [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/)). This would allow you to use relative paths in your AJAX request, while the HTTP server would be acting as a proxy to any "remote" location.

The fundamental configuration directive to set up a reverse proxy in mod_proxy is the ProxyPass. You would typically use it as follows:

```
ProxyPass     /web-services/     http://third-party.com/web-services/
```

In this case, the browser would be requesting `/web-services/service.json` but the server would serve this by acting as a proxy to `http://third-party.com/web-services/service.json`.

If you are using [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services), you may want to use the [Managed Fusion URL Rewriter and Reverse Proxy](http://www.codeplex.com/Wikipage?ProjectName=urlrewriter) to set up the reverse proxy.

---

**EDIT:**

Further to the comment below, since the web service is on the same domain, there is no need to worry about the same origin policy. Simply use [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest). You can start by checking out the article at ajaxpatterns.org:

- [XMLHttpRequest Call](http://ajaxpatterns.org/XMLHttpRequest_Call)

Comment: I am requesting data from the same domain, so what do i need to do in this case?

Comment: If your webservice is on the same domain, you can use AJAX using XMLHttpRequest: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest. You will be returned the data in the `responseText` property.

Answer (score 2):

Using jquery

```
$.getJSON(myResourceFileURL,
 function parseResults(json){
    //json is the contents of the file
 }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're using JQuery:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Your text file will be passed to the "success" function that you set up. Your success function can write the contents to the page, using a document.write or similar.